# How to set cursor position in Codemirror editor

Tags: javascript, codemirror, cursor-position

I am implementing **"find and correct"** functionality using codemirror. I know there is an addon for **search and replace**, but it doesn't fulfill my requirement. the editor is for writing particular queries. It creates spans in

`<pre>
     <span class="cm-field">field</span>:jet <span class="cm-other-operator active" >adj3</span> engine <span class="cm-operator">OR</span> jet <span class="cm-other-operator" >near5</span> engine 
</pre>`

please refer snapshot.
If i click on any of the operator (orange colored), the cursor starts blinking there and the functionality is working. On clicking **find next** button i am able to find the respective span but unble to set cursor there. So How can i set Cursor position there. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: You can use doc.setCursor(pos: {line, ch}) to set the cursror to any specific position.

Comment: On CodeMirror 6, the cursor position is a single number: `editor.dispatch({selection: {anchor: N, head: N}})` https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/set-cursor-position-in-v6/4476

Answer (score 26):

Before you set the cursor position you have to focus on the editor.

```
editor.focus()
```

Then just like [@djadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1618788/djadmin) said you would use [`doc.setCursor(pos: {line, ch})`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setCursor) to set the cursor position.

```
editor.setCursor({line: 1, ch: 5})
```

Here's a JSFiddle you can play with that does this: https://jsfiddle.net/stpmu61y/

Comment: Could you specify whether the line and ch (column) are 0- or 1-indexed?

Comment: There's no such function on CodeMirror 6

Answer (score 2):

If your cursor is installed, but only at the beginning of the line: 0, symbol: 0, this means that only focus is triggered, since setValue is delayed, wrap your SetCursor in SetTimeOut with 0 delay and enjoy =)

```js
       codeEditor.setValue (code);

       setTimeout (() => {
           codeEditor.focus();
           codeEditor.setCursor({
             line: 3,
             ch: 10,
           });
       }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using https://uiwjs.github.io/react-codemirror/,

```
const codemirrorRef = React.useRef();
```

```
      <CodeMirror
        ref={codemirrorRef}
```

```
    codemirrorRef.current.view.dispatch({selection: {anchor: 5, head: 5}})
```